# Where is the log file using Production profile with NServiceBus GenericHost and default log4net settings when installed as a service?

Tags: log4net, nservicebus

I have a very simple NServiceBus.Host.exe application that is using the default logging and the Production profile.  According to [the documentation](http://www.nservicebus.com/Profiles.aspx), this should result in an appending file log that should appear in the same folder as the EXE.  However, when I run the application as a service, the log file doesn't appear in the same folder as the EXE, and thus far I've been unable to locate it at all.  The service is running as Local System.  Do I need to run it as a user account and look for the file in the AppData folder somewhere?  Is it under c:\windows somewhere?  Where is it and is there a way for me to have it actually log to a file in the same folder as the EXE as advertised?

**Update:**
Using ProcMon and ProcExp from SysInternals, I can see that there is no attempt to create any log file in the folder where my EXE exists, nor are there any file permission errors while trying to create a log file anywhere, at least not from the PID of the service (if for some reason log4net spins up another process to do this work then I might have missed it).

Comment: Try looking in c:\windows\temp

Comment: @hugh - nothing in c:\windows\temp :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the service wasn't actually running in the Production profile.  I had for some reason gotten it into my head that services would run in the production profile by default, while running it in interactive mode would use Lite by default.  Not so - the service will use the Lite profile unless you specify otherwise.  I changed my command to install the service from:
NServiceBus.Host.exe /install /displayName:MyService
to
NServiceBus.Host.exe /install /displayName:MyService NServiceBus.Production

and this fixed the issue.